# How to ensure the license for GitHub PRs?

Tags: licensing, github, pull-request

My GitHub repository is licensed with CC BY-SA license.

When people suggest PRs, and I accept them, do they automatically fall under the same license as the rest of the project?

If not, how can I ensure the right licensing for PRs?

Comment: Get them to sign a CLA.

Comment: @curiousdannii yeah got it already, you could specify that as an answer as well! :)

Comment: See also: [When folks send me pull-requests on GitHub, what are their copyright/licensing terms by default?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2611/138)

Answer (score 5):

I found a service https://cla-assistant.io, recommended by https://cla.github.com.
Makes a hook to ensure every contributor signs the CLA.

Looks good so far. Will try and see how it goes.