# Does a BSD-3 repository own Pull Requests?

Tags: licensing, github, bsd, contributor-agreements, pull-request

I submit a large PR to repository X. Later, I close the PR and make my own repository that uses some of X's code, and give X due attribution in the NOTICE file and function docstrings. At time of dispute, my repository is private and not distributed, though I can change that.

If I explicitly forbid it, is X allowed to 1) reopen the PR and commit it to X, 2) use code in my PR to publish an academic work? This [related Q&A](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2611/21059) doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It seems like the [second answer in your linked Q&A](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/10044/50) says the PR was in fact licensed under BSD, per GitHub's terms. This question does differ slightly, though, because it also includes an attempt to actively rescind that BSD grant. [This Q&A](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4012/50) addresses the question of revocability when unspecified in the license, but it hinges on the question of whether the licensed code was offered in exchange for some "consideration". A good answer might address the application of this criterion to this case.